# Notepad++ Python Script - Check if next-to-last line contains specific string

Tags: python, notepad++

I need to write a Python script for Notepad++ (using http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/), which finds PHP files if their next-to-last line contains `?>` tag.

In other words, it should find files like:

```
<?php
whatever_goes_here
?>
...
```

and NOT files like:

```
<?php
whatever_goes_here
?>
```

My script is following:

```
import os;
import sys;
filePathSrc="C:\\Temp\\some_directory"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filePathSrc):
    for fn in files:
      if fn[-4:] == '.php':
        notepad.open(root + "\\" + fn)
        console.write(root + "\\" + fn + "\r\n")
        end_position=editor.getTextLength()
        start_position=end_position-5
        editor.findText(FINDOPTION.MATCHCASE, start_position, end_position, "?>")
```

However, it does nothing (except properly opening *.php file). No errors are displayed in console. What am I missing here?

P.S. if someone is interested why I use use only the last 5 symbols of file as start_position, it's because I need to find only `?>` tags that are at the very end of file (and every PHP file I search for has an empty line without any symbols as the final line).

Comment: notepad, console, and editor aren't defined in this code

Comment: But no errors are displayed. Also, if I use exactly the same code (just change a line with "editor.findText" command to any other "editor.xxxxxx" command), it works perfectly without defining notepad, console, or editor.

Comment: I assume `editor.findText` actually returns something, and you're doing nothing with that result

Comment: Yes, it should highlight text which was found (like I said, file gets opened successfully). But that doesn't happen.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand what that method does. You can simply open a filesystem in standard python, and read the lines of a file, and grab the last one, if that's all you want

Comment: Let me explain a bit more: the script should find string in files and if files contain string, leave them opened in Notepad++. If not, close them. However, I can'g go that far because I can't get past findtext function.

Comment: Why do you expect an error?  Your findtext() function probably returns a value, representing a match/no match and you don't seem to do anything with it with this code snippet.  From the looks of this, all it will do is open all the .php files in your directory.